# Using date variables outside Wordpress loop to display Adsense

Tags: wordpress

I want to show adsense ads only on those posts and pages which are written in the year 2011 using variables outside the "loop". It there any way of doing it in wordpress ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using variables in the Wordpress loop. The "loop" is commonly used for pulling data like this. This answer is only applicable if you plan to put the ad within the Wordpress loop.

This snippet of code can help you get started:

if(the_time('Y')=='2011') {
echo adsense_custom_function();
}

See more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action#Title.2C_Date_and_Author

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want this without Wordpress Loop

Comment: Ok just make sure you clarify that in your question.